# How do I implement AssemblyAnnotationWriter to print metadata

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am learning how to write passes in llvm. I am trying to implement

`virtual void emitFunctionAnnot(const Function *, formatted_raw_ostream &){}`

as given at http://llvm.org/doxygen/AssemblyAnnotationWriter_8h_source.html
to print `#[uses]=1` before start of a function.

The code below works if I manually call `emitFunctionAnnot(&F, ferrs());` inside `runOnFunction()` method, which(`emitFunctionAnnot`) I have overridden. However shouldn't it work without calling it manullay because that's the whole point of overriding it. I believe I am doing something wrong while overriding. I have spent countless hours trying to debug it. I would appreciate any help.

This is what I have so far.

```cpp
#include "llvm/Pass.h"
#include "llvm/PassManager.h"
#include "llvm/Transforms/IPO/PassManagerBuilder.h"
#include "llvm/DebugInfo.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"
#include "llvm/Support/FormattedStream.h"
#include "llvm/Support/InstIterator.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Instruction.h"
#include "llvm/DebugInfo.h"
#include "llvm/Assembly/AssemblyAnnotationWriter.h"


#include <ostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace llvm;

namespace {


class CommentWriter : public AssemblyAnnotationWriter {
public:
 virtual void emitFunctionAnnot(const Function *F,
                         formatted_raw_ostream &OS) {
    OS << "; [#uses=" << F->getNumUses() << ']';  // Output # uses
    OS << '\n';
  }

};

class FunctionInfo : public FunctionPass, public AssemblyAnnotationWriter{

public:
  static char ID;
  FunctionInfo() : FunctionPass(ID) {}

 void emitFunctionAnnot(const Function *F, formatted_raw_ostream &OS) {
    errs() << "CALLED";
    OS << "; [#uses=" << F->getNumUses() << ']';  // Output # uses
    OS << '\n';
  }


  virtual bool runOnFunction(Function &F) {

//  emitFunctionAnnot(&F, ferrs());
    for (inst_iterator I = inst_begin(F), E = inst_end(F); I != E; ++I){
      Instruction &II = *I;
      errs() << *I;

    }
    return false;
  }


  virtual void getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &AU) const {
    AU.setPreservesAll();
  }
};


char FunctionInfo::ID = 0;

//    clang -c -Xclang -load -Xclang ./FunctionInfo.so loop.c
static void registerMyPass(const PassManagerBuilder &,
                           PassManagerBase &PM) {
    PM.add(new FunctionInfo());
}
RegisterStandardPasses
    RegisterMyPass(PassManagerBuilder::EP_EarlyAsPossible,
                   registerMyPass);

    RegisterPass<FunctionInfo> X("function-info", "Function Information");

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annotations exist only as comments in an LLVM IR printout. They are not actually a part of the IR, and consequently they are not something you "add" in a pass.

The way to use an `AssemblyAnnotationWriter` is to pass it as the 2nd argument to a `print` function (e.g. `Module::print`). You can do that *inside* a pass, but it's not something that is done automatically for you. Specifically, making the pass inherit from `AssemblyAnnotationWriter` is nonsensical - the first approach you've shown in your question, inheriting from it in a separate class, is the correct approach.

In short, if you want a printout of the module in your pass, call `print` on it. If you want to add comments to the printout, call the same `print` but pass an instance of your `CommentWriter` as the 2nd argument.